# Alerting the state of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i know it may be some silly mistake that i am doing. My problem is that i want to display the state of the checkbox.. While clicking on a checkbox, if its getting checked, then it will be displayed checked, if its getting unchecked, it will alert unchecked..

but my problem is that, whether its checked or unchecked, its always displaying checked...

here my sample code, at first the jquery or javascript

```
function increase_seat()
{
   if($(this).prop("checked", true))
        alert("checked");
   else if($(this).prop("checked", false))
        alert("unchecked");
}
```

and the php/html script is

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {?>

              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $i;?>" class="check" />
       <?php
        }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the property **checked** instead of getting the `value` of property. Check the prop [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). You can use `is(":checked")` with checkbox to find out checked status.

Change to

*Html*

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="increase_seat(this);" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php
```

echo $i;?>" class="check" />

*Javascript*

```
function increase_seat(source)
{
   if($(source).is(":checked"))
          alert("checked");
    else 
          alert("unchecked");
}
```

*Its better to use attr instead of using prop if you have jQuery 1.7 or above.*

Comment: I realised that you might not have access to this made little change check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this:

```
if( $(this).is(":checked") )
    alert("checked");
else
    alert("unchecked");
```

What you are doing in the code is **setting** and not **getting** the property.

Comment: Dude, you aren't giving anything to the `this`. Okay, I guess there will be a lot of checkboxes in your page right? So to find which it is referring, you need to give the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($('#TestCheck').prop("checked"))
{
        alert("checked");
}
else 
{
       alert("unchecked");
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/akCmS/2/)

From Documentation:

.prop("checked") ----   true (Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is(":checked")` property as follows:

## Sample Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked") === true){
        alert("Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Unchecked");
    }
    });
});​
```

## Working Fiddle

here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxLjT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a "1" or "0" result instead of blank, you should be using **radio buttons**. Set both buttons to unselected, then validate by requiring an option to be selected.